# Exception message to UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, exception, jquery-ui

I open a jQuery dialog, in this box I do a save/cancel. To Save, I call my controller, make some validation, save or throw Exception (MyPersonalException). If there is exception, I return an another View (the "MessageError" view) to display in the popup. I just want to see in the modal box the message available in "MyPersonalException"

My questions :
1. That's work but only with Firefox not IE not Chrome
2. Is there an other way because that's look a lof of code to just diplay a message.

The controller look like this :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveOrUpdate(Guid id, string firstName, string LastName)
{
    try
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee() { Id = id, FirstName = firstName, LastName = LastName };
        _employeeService.SaveOrUpdate(employee);
        return Index();
    }
    catch (MyPersonalException ex)
    {
        _model.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return View("MessageError", _model);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _model.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return View("MessageError", _model);
    }
}
```

To call the dialog box, I use this code

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        /* var name = $("#firstName"),
        email = $("#lastName"),
        password = $("#isActive"),
        allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
        tips = $("#validateTips");*/

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Save: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Employee/SaveOrUpdate",
                    data: {
                        id: getId(),
                        firstName: getFirstName(),
                        lastName: getLastName()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (jqueryShowResult(data))
                            $("#DisplayError").html(data);
                        else {
                            employeeId = 0;
                            $(this).dialog('close');                               
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                })

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                employeeId = 0;
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $("#gridEmpoyee").trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        open: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Employee/GetEmployee",
                data: {
                    id: employeeId
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#employeeDetail").html(data);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

});

The jQueryShowResult

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jqueryShowResult = function(msg) {
        var browser;
        try //Internet Explorer
                    {
            xmlDocTest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            browser = "IE";
        }
        catch (e) {
            browser = "FF";
        }

        if (browser == "IE") {
            try {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(msg);
                var message = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var code = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                return false;
            }
            catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {

            var code = $(msg).find('code').text();
            var message = $(msg).find('message').text();
            if (code == "500") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }; 
 </script>
```

Comment: I updated the answer below, this should allow you to do what you want without customizing the jQuery ajax object at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Sorry, we use a custom wrapper. jQuery by default does not include the xmlHttpRequest in success.  Below is another approach, this works without changing your view at all.  You're basically just checking for the element with `id='code'` in the response, if it exists, display the error.

```
success: function(data, textStatus) {
  if ($("#code",data).length) { //See if the element <whatever id='code'> exists
    $("#DisplayError").html(data);
  } else {
    employeeId = 0;
    $(this).dialog('close');                               
  }
},
```

Here's the jQuery 1.4 Version (See [changes here](http://jquery14.com/day-01), note the *Success callback receives XHR object as third argument*):

First, set the StatusCode to 210 in your view `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 210;`, then use this callback format:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  if (xhr.status == 210) {
    $("#DisplayError").html(data);
  } else {
    employeeId = 0;
    $(this).dialog('close');                               
  }
},
```

Comment: Then I still have to use the "jqueryShowResult" ? IS it working on FF, IE, Chrome ?

Comment: No need for `jQueryShowResult` with this solution, it should work in all browsers, you're simply looking for an element with `id='code'` strictly within the ajax result, that's what the `,data` does on the selector.

Comment: May be you can give us your customer wrapper :)

Comment: Actually you won't need it...this isn't an uncommon need and was added for jQuery 1.4: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  When you change from 1.3.2 to 1.4 you can use the previous method I posted, click on the link beside edited to see the previous answer and go that route.

Comment: @Kris-I Answer is updated to include both, check out the jQuery changes link I included to see other 1.4 stuff, including a short description of the success callback change.